# Skipping tinymce image-upload modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using the [tinymce-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) gem and the [tinymce-rails-imageupload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload) gem for image uploads in an editor. I've looked around and cannot find a way to change the default upload process. Instead of clicking the image button in the toolbar and getting a modal-popup to upload an image and add a caption, I'd like the image button in the toolbar to act as a 'choose file' button and directly open the file finder. Is this possible with tinymce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Quick and dirty monkey patch **[here](http://pastebin.com/qbzbZpKE)**

No additional window between button press and system file selection dialog and image is inserted right after file was selected. In my chrome 40.0.2214.111 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) seems to work as expected.

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload.git
cd tinymce-rails-imageupload

# substitute app/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js with a patched version

gem build tinymce-rails-imageupload.gemspec
gem install ./tinymce-rails-imageupload-4.0.16.beta.gem
```

Below is a diff between modified and master branch github version
(Wed Feb 25 10:34:49 2015 +0100)

```
diff plugin-modified.js tinymce-rails-imageupload/app/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js 

12,17d11
<       function Dialog() {
<         if (document.getElementsByName("file")[0].value) {
<           insertImage();
<         } else ed.windowManager.close;
<       }
< 
19,20d12
<             if(win) {win.close()};
< 
26,27c18,19
<             {type: 'iframe',  url: 'javascript:void(0)', style: 'display: none'},
<             {type: 'textbox', name: 'file', label: ed.translate('Choose an image'), subtype: 'file', onchange: Dialog},
---
>             {type: 'iframe',  url: 'javascript:void(0)'},
>             {type: 'textbox', name: 'file', label: ed.translate('Choose an image'), subtype: 'file'},
103,112d94
<         win.hide();
<        
< 
<         var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
<                                         "view": window,
<                                         "bubbles": true,
<                                         "cancelable": false});
<         clickEvent.toElement=document.getElementsByName("file")[0];
<         document.getElementsByName("file")[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
<
```

---

No special knob to do it there, only by rewriting [this function](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js#L12)...

I think you will need to leave their iframe for the fields that backend expects on upload, but you can make it invisible, just open file selection dialog in showDialog and call insertImage after file was selected.

Comment: Hey Evgeny, thanks for the answer however you lost me at the part about leaving the iframe.

Comment: Oh, there are resudes of my experiments, you actually can directly call insertImage on change of the textbox. And "style:" on line 26 is not nesessary too.  But it works ok as it is now, it's just an idea, for the production i'd recommend remove all unnessesary elements leaving just a compact hidden form. And set an alt text to something and sizes too.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience but where do I actually place the new function. Do I create a plugin.js file, an 'initializers/.rb' file or something else?

Comment: my first code snipplet are unix shell commands - it will download imageupload gem source, you modify plugin.js and build-install this new gem in place of original one

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi @EvgenyPetrov , if I'd like to change config.js, how would I update the gem? Would I have to repeat the 'gem build' step?

Comment: No, you won't need to rebuild the gem, except if you change something in the gem source.

Comment: I'm guessing I'll have to rebuild after modifying plugin.js then. Will the 'gem install ./tinymce-rails-imageupload-4.0.16.beta.gem' line be the same?

Comment: Yes, gem name shouldn't change

Comment: Hmm, so I deleted line 255 to stop showing an 'insert image from your computer' label. Then saved file and ran 'gem build tinymce-rails-imageupload.gemspec' and
'gem install ./tinymce-rails-imageupload-4.0.16.beta.gem'. Still no luck

Comment: @user2759575 By the way consider changing the gem name and maybe pushing it to repository to avoid deployment problems in future.

Comment: Is the '4.0.16' of any significance or can it be any #?

Comment: It's a .gem file name created after building in same directory where the gemspec is, you can just list and see it's there.

Comment: Ah Ok. I'm still having trouble rebuilding it though so this line is deleted.